# "Why do power lines use high voltage?" Loss in power equal to Current*Voltage?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

I define P is the average power. So $P=IV$ and $I=\frac{P}{V}$.
$P_{loss}$ I define to be the power loss, which is equal to $I^2R$.

Substituting for $I$, $P_{loss} = \frac {P^2R}{V^2}$

So I get that the you need high voltage to minimise heat loss as R and P are constant.

However, I am confused about the following: Can I solve $P_{loss}=I^2R$ into $P_{loss}=IV$? I don't see why I can't, however, I am confident that I can't do this as then the loss in power would be equal to the average power, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why high voltage transmission lines?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145301/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High voltage power lines - clarification of energy loss](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248229/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $P=IV$ expression includes the power delivered by the line to the users at the far end. The $I^2R$ is the part of the $IV$ power that does *not* get delivered to them.

To be more precise:  Let $R_{\rm line} $ be the resistence of the line and $R_{\rm load}$ then
$R_{\rm total}= R_{\rm line}+R_{\rm load}$ and
$$
IV = I^2 R_{\rm total}=I^2 R_{\rm line}+ I^2R_{\rm load}.
$$
The first term $I^2 R_{\rm line}$ is the loss and the second term $I^2R_{\rm load}$ is the useful power delivered to the user.

Comment: But does $I^2R$ not equal $IV$? If not, why?

Comment: @photon The V for the power loss isn't the voltage delivered, but the loss of voltage between the generator and the users. That depends on the current delivered, but not on the voltage delivered.

Comment: [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/501014/66086) might help you.

Comment: I'll edit my answer.